# How can I define touch area for pin (Skobbler iOS)

Tags: ios, touch, skmaps

After updating to latest Skobbler version I noticed that touchable area around pin was increased. Before when I touched pin, `didSelectAnnotation` method triggered well. But now if I touch map nearby the pin, `didSelectAnnotation` also triggered. I want to make clickable just the pin picture, not the area around. 
I've tried this with a custom pin and with a standard. The same result.

May be there is a settings property? I looked through the documentation but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the touch area is not configurable.

In 2.3 it was indeed increased (to make clicking annotations easier) - we'll revisit this decision in a later update, but for the time being you'll have work around this implementation.

Comment: Hi @Ando, has this been addressed since 2.3? I'm using 2.5.1 for both Android and iOS and I would like to know if there is built-in functionality to increase the touchable area of an annotation. While the OP here wanted to decrease the clickable area, I would like to increase it. I'm assuming I can add transparency to the images included in the SDK to fake it, but I was hoping for a built in method with more control. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Hi @Keith. Currently there is no programmatic support for doing this - the only way would be to tweak the annotation's icon & padding.

Comment: Thanks @Ando, sounds good, that's what we ended up doing. appreciate it!